# C++ LibCurl - Converting CURLcode into a CString

Tags: c++, libcurl, cstring

What would be the easiest way to convert the "res" variable (CURLcode) into a CString?

Here's the standard example which compiles fine on my machine but I want to use this in a MFC app and display the result as a MessageBox. Any help is appreciated!

```
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    /* always cleanup */ 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `curl_easy_strerror` function.

```
CString str(curl_easy_strerror(res));
```

or

```
CString str;
str.Format("curl_easy_perform return %s [%d]",curl_easy_strerror(res),res);
```

Comment: It seems you need to use curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER,myBuffer) first, based on http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html

Comment: For some reason I can't get CString to be recognized. I'm including `curl/curl.h`, do I need anything else?

Answer (score 3):

A `CURLcode` is a number, so after 4 seconds on Google and having never used MFC, I found you can do this:

```
CString str;
str.Format("%d", res);
```

Comment: Color me embarassed. Thank you

Comment: @kogh The second answer is probably a lot better, converting into a sensible string instead of a number only.